# How to add image field to module install file

Tags: 7, media, installation

How to add image field to database in module install file? I found on api documentation, that type is image, so tried the following code:

```
function profile_bg_schema() {

$schema = array();

$schema['profile_bg'] = array(
  'description' => 'The table containing backgrounds',
  'fields' => array(
    'bid' => array(
      'description' => 'The primary identifier for the background.',
      'type' => 'serial',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'image' => array(
      'description' => 'The background image.',
      'type' => 'image',
      'not null' => TRUE,
      'default' => '',
    ),
    'class' => array(
      'description' => 'The class added to div.',
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => 255,
      'not null' => TRUE,
      'default' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'primary key' => array('bid'),
);


$schema['profile_bg_unlock'] = array(
  'description' => 'User - background - active table',
  'fields' => array(
    'uid' => array(
      'description' => 'User ID.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
     'bid' => array(
      'description' => 'Background ID.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
    ),
    'status' => array(
      'description' => 'The primary identifier for the background.',
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'not null' => TRUE,
      'default' => '0',
    ),
  ),
);

return $schema;

}
```

First I was getting an error about image field, now module becomes ON, but nothing changes in database.

---- EDIT ----
Error below. It looks like Drupal do not know what type of field should create in database.

```
   Notice: Undefined index: image:normal w DatabaseSchema_mysql->processField() (linia 205 z C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\drupal\includes\database\mysql\schema.inc).
    PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Background Img.', `class` VARCHAR unsigned NOT NULL DEFAU' at line 3: CREATE TABLE {profile_bg} ( `bid` INT unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'bg ID.', `image` DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Background Img.', `class` VARCHAR unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'css class for the background.', PRIMARY KEY (`bid`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'background table'; Array ( ) w db_create_table() (linia 2720 z C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\drupal\includes\database\database.inc).
```

Comment: From what I know `image` itself is not stored in the DB but an address is saved. mysql is a relational Database what you need is an object or an object-relational Database which be able to save videos, images and files.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the wrong documentation. Please read [Data Types](https://www.drupal.org/node/159605) instead. There is no `image` type for database field.

The available data type are:

- serial
- int
- float
- numeric
- varchar
- char
- text
- blob

Since Drupal manage file (including image files) in `file_managed` table with key `fid`. What you need is to create a `int` column for storing the value of foreign key `fid`. The column definition should be:

```php
'image_fid' => array(
  'description' => 'The {file_managed}.fid being referenced in this field.',
  'type' => 'int',
  'not null' => FALSE,
  'unsigned' => TRUE,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual "image" field type in your database. You'll want to create it in hook_schema() as a regular "int" field. Then on the form that will process the image, you'll have a "managed_file" form element that processes the file. Finally, in your form submission, save the file FID number in the "int" field in your database.

Something like the below should work:

```
function mymodule_form($form, $form_state) {

    $form['logo_upload'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#title' => t('Logo'),
        '#description' => t('Upload a logo.'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
        '#default_value' => $entity->logo, // make sure to set the default value to the current file FID saved in your database field
    );

    $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#submit' => array('mymodule_form_submit'),
    );

    return $form;
}

function mymodule_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // $form_state['values']['logo_upload'] is the file FID number, but it is
    // still in temporary status. So load the file, and update the status to permanent.

    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['logo_upload']);
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);

    $form_state['values']['logo'] = $file->fid;

    // at this point, $form_state['values']['logo'] is the file FID of the uploaded
    // file. Save this value in your "int" field in the database.
}
```